# open conditional python files but read data from one

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I want to open and read a file depending on a condition, read only if condition met true. I wrote the following scriptlet:

```
def bb(fname, species):
     if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
         pm =  open('file.txt', 'rU')
         for line in pm:
             line = line.split()
             with open(fname, 'rU') as user:
                 for e in user:
                     e = e.split()
                     if e[0] in line:
                         print(line)
    elif species in ('human', 'hs'):
         pm =  open('file2.txt', 'rU')
         for line in pm:
             line = line.split()
             with open(fname, 'rU') as user:
                 for e in user:
                     e = e.split()
                     if e[0] in line:
                         print(line)
```

Is there a proper pythonic way, where I don't have to repeat/write the same lines (line3 to 10) over and over again ? Thanks !

Comment: You made a function, why not make another one for just opening files?

Comment: The two pieces of code are exactly identical. what is the point of your `if` if you run the same code anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the filename value in a variable

```
def bb(fname, species):
    if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
        fname2 = 'file.txt'
    elif species in ('human', 'hs'):
        fname2 = 'file2.txt'
    else:
        raise ValueError("species received illegal value")

    with  open(fname2, 'rU') as pm:
        for line in pm:
            line = line.split()
            with open(fname, 'rU') as user:
                for e in user:
                    e = e.split()
                    if e[0] in line:
                        print(line)
```

or define another function

```
def bb(fname, species):
    if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
        read_file('file.txt', fname)
    elif species in ('human', 'hs'):
        read_file('file2.txt', fname)

def read_file(fname1, fname2):
    with  open(fname1, 'rU') as pm:
        for line in pm:
            line = line.split()
            with open(fname2, 'rU') as user:
                for e in user:
                    e = e.split()
                    if e[0] in line:
                        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be doing the exact same thing regardless of the condition, you could just collapse everything?

```
def bb(fname, species):
     if species in ['yeast', 'sc', 'human', 'hs']:
         pm =  open('file.txt', 'rU')
         for line in pm:
             line = line.split()
             with open(fname, 'rU') as user:
                 for e in user:
                     e = e.split()
                     if e[0] in line:
                         print(line)
```

Either that or you've made a mistake copying the code. If you want to do something different depending on the case, then you could make a function that takes that argument, or do the conditional statement first and use it to set a certain string or value.

E.g.

```
if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
    permissions = 'rU'
```

etc.

---

Edit: Ah, with your edited question the answer would be as above but then

```
if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
    file_name = 'file.txt'
elif species in ('human', 'hs'):
    file_name = 'file2.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put opening of file in `if else` case rest will be done in a similar manner and same code block as well.

```
def bb(fname, species):
    if species in ('yeast', 'sc'):
             pm =  open('file.txt', 'rU')
    elif species in ('human', 'hs'):
             pm =  open('file2.txt', 'rU')
         for line in pm:
             line = line.split()
             with open(fname, 'rU') as user:
                 for e in user:
                     e = e.split()
                     if e[0] in line:
                         print(line)
```